# Adding minutes to a custom date time column

Tags: excel, datetime

I have a column of date with custom date time format

```
mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss.000 AM/PM
```

I have another column with 1 minute.

How do I add these two columns?

or

How to add just a minute to 1st column?

e.g)

```
A                               B                               C

03/24/2014 6:59:27.823 PM     0/00/0000  0:01:00.000 PM     03/24/2014 7:00:27.823 PM  
03/25/2014 4:57:31.637 PM     0/00/0000  0:01:00.000 PM     03/25/2014 4:58:31.637 PM 
06/04/2014 12:47:50.387 PM    0/00/0000  0:01:00.000 PM     06/04/2014 12:48:50.387 PM
```

Column **C** is the result I want

I tried the following but its now working.

**1) A2+B2**

- This doesnt work - gives me `!VALUE` as output

**2) A2 + Minute(0.000694)**

- This gives me wrong output too
  Also

`A1+1` adds the `1` to the day and gives me

```
03/25/2014 6:59:27.823 PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the values in column **B** with:

```
=TIME(0,1,0)
```

Comment: cool. Thanks it worked. based on yours I also tried Minute(.500694)+B2 and it worked!

Comment: very good.......I like the **=TIME()** function because it handles hours, minutes, seconds without any math.